# What do you get for 5 kills in a round in Demolition?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

1 kill = Proceed to next weapon

2 kills = Proceed + Frag grenade

3 kills = Proceed + Flashbang

4 kills = Proceed + PyroGrenade

5 kills = Proceed + ???

I just want to know what is the bonus for eliminating the whole enemy team in one round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this out and you get the incendiary grenade as a Counter-Terrorist and the Molotov as a Terrorist. So it doesn't appear to be any difference between 4 and 5 kills.